# Can't find the reason why value stored to 'delta' isn't read

Tags: c

While analyzing  can't seem to avoid the value stored to 'delta' not being read... what part of my loop isn't working and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b, c;
    float delta;
    printf("a=");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("b=");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("c=");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    float x, x1, x2;
    delta=((b*b)-(4*a*c));
    if("delta==0")
    {
        x=((-b)/(2*a));
        printf("x=%f \n", x);
    }
    else if("delta>0")
    {
        x1=((-b+sqrt(delta))/(2*a));
        x2=((-b-sqrt(delta))/(2*a));
        printf("x1=%f i x2=%f \n", x1, x2);
    }
    else printf("Nie ma w zbiorze liczb rzeczywistych rozwiazania tego rownania.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not put your if - condition into ". Be wary of FLOAT and == comparison. use `if(delta == 0)` and `if (delta>0)`. Using a debugger, setting a breakpoint would have told you as much...

Comment: `if("delta==0")` is always true because you're testing the pointer on a string literal against 0. should be ` if(delta==0)`

Comment: `if("delta==0")`? That's a ***string*** you put in the condition, it will always be "true". Did you mean `if(delta==0)` (without the quotes)?

Comment: Float to 0 comparison:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837576/comparing-floating-point-number-to-zero its c++ but the reasons are same.

Comment: testing against string also explains why you're getting a warning against `delta` not being read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing, `if("delta==0")` inside "" whatever is present that will be treated as a address so if(address) means true, remove the double quotation.

```
if(delta==0)
    // some code
 else if (delta > 0)
    // some code
```

2nd thing, you are comparing(==) a float & an integer, so be aware of behaviour of comparing different operands.