# Line Follower based on Image Processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, hough-transform

I’m starting to work on a line follower project but it is required that I use image processing techniques. I have a few ideas to consider, but I would like some input as there are some doubts I would like to clarify. This is my approach to solve this problem: I first read the image, then apply thresholding to detect the object (the line). I do color filtering and then edge detection. After this I start to do image classification to detect all the lines, then extrapolate those lines to only output/detect parallel lines (like a lane detection algorithm). With this parallel lines I can calculate the center to maintain my vehicle centered and the angle to make turns.

I do not know the angles in the path so the system must be able to turn any angle, that’s why I will calculate the angle. I have included a picture of a line with a turn, this is the kind of turns I will be dealing with. I have managed to implement almost everything. My main problem is in the change of angle, basically the turns. After I have detected the parallel lines, how can I make my system know when is time to make a turn? The question might be kind of confusing, but basically the vehicle will be moving forward as long the angle is near to zero. But when the vehicle approach a turn, it might detect two set of parallel lines. Maybe I can define a length of the detected lines that will define whether or not the vehicle must move forward?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lines (the center line of each path):

```
y1 = m1 * x + b1
y2 = m2 * x + b2
```

They intersect when you choose an x such that y1 and y2 are equal (if they are not parallel of course, so m1 != m2)

```
m1 * x + b1 = m2 * x + b2
```

(do a bunch of algebra)

```
x  = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
(y should be the same for both line formulas)
```

When you are near this point, switch lines.

NOTE: This won't handle the case of perfectly vertical lines, because they have infinite slope, and no y-intercept -- for that see the [parametric form of lines](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218081901/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52965.html).  You will have 2 equations per line:

```
x = f1(t1)
y = f2(t1)
```

and

```
x = f3(t2)
y = f4(t2)
```

Set `f1(t1) == f3(t2)` and `f2(t1) == f4(t2)` to find the intersection of non-parallel lines.  Then plug `t1` into the first line formula to find `(x, y)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889178/15485) by [Lou Franco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3937/lou-franco) explains you how to get the intersection of the two center line of each path and then that intersection is a good point to start your turn.

I would add a suggestion on how to compute the center line of a path.

In my experience, when working with floating point representation of lines extracted from images, the lines are really never parallel, they just intersect usually at a point that falls out of the image (maybe far away).

The following C++ function `bisector_of_lines` is inspired by the method `bisector_of_linesC2` found at [CGAL source code](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/releases/CGAL-4.11/Cartesian_kernel/include/CGAL/constructions/kernel_ftC2.h#L251).

A line is expressed as [`a*x+b*y+c=0`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Line__2.html), the following function 
constructs the bisector of the two lines `p` and `q`.

`line p is pa*x+pb*y+pc=0`

`line q is qa*x+qb*y+qc=0`

The `a`, `b`, `c` of the bisector line are the last three parameters of the function: `a`, `b` and `c`.

In the general case, the bisector has the direction of the vector which is the sum of the normalized directions of the two lines, and which passes through the intersection of `p` and `q`. If `p` and `q` are parallel, then the bisector is defined as the line which has the same direction as `p`, and which is at the same distance from `p` and `q` (see the official CGAL documentation for [`CGAL::Line_2<Kernel> CGAL::bisector`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__bisector__grp.html#gaf9a5b5ad26e76e31f1329a065b900e09)).

```
void
bisector_of_lines(const double &pa, const double &pb, const double &pc,
            const double &qa, const double &qb, const double &qc,
            double &a, double &b, double &c)
{
  // We normalize the equations of the 2 lines, and we then add them.
  double n1 = sqrt(pa*pa + pb*pb);
  double n2 = sqrt(qa*qa + qb*qb);
  a = n2 * pa + n1 * qa;
  b = n2 * pb + n1 * qb;
  c = n2 * pc + n1 * qc;

  // Care must be taken for the case when this produces a degenerate line.
  if (a == 0 && b == 0) {// maybe it is best to replace == with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837576/comparing-floating-point-number-to-zero
    a = n2 * pa - n1 * qa;
    b = n2 * pb - n1 * qb;
    c = n2 * pc - n1 * qc;
  }
}
```