# C++ Endless loop with function sin x problem

Tags: c++, loops, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am practicing for my final exam and professor sent us a last year's copy and in it, there is this assignment:
[image: Image of assignment]

I made a code for it, but it seems it doesn't work properly, it ends up in an endless loop most of the times. This is my code:

```cpp
int main(){
    double x;
    double sinx;
    int n=1;
    int sign=-1;
    cin>>x;
    sinx=0;
    for(;;) {
        int fact=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=2*n+1;i++){
            fact*=i;
        }
        double term=pow(x,2*n+1)/fact;
        if(term==0){
            break;
        }
        sinx += term * sign;
        sign *= -1;
        n++;

    }
    cout<<sinx;
}
```

I really tried everything.

Comment: Note that `x^5 / 5!` is equal to `(x^3 / 3!) * (x^2 / (4*5))` and so on - you don't need to calculate factorials and powers on each iteration.

Comment: I think you underestimate how fast factorials are growing. 13! is already too big to store in an `int`, so if your loop goes to `n == 6`, you are already in Undefined Behaviour land.

Comment: The usual suspects are `int` not beeing a wide enough type to contain high factorials and `double` values not playing well with equal comparisons.

Comment: Very related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) `term==0` might never be true.

Comment: *"it ends up in an endless loop most of the times."* -- Well, you did write a nominally infinite loop (a `for` with no condition). I think the onus is on you to demonstrate why the loop should end. What is supposed to end the loop (`term` being `0.0`)? What are the values you are seeing? *(Output `term` before the `if` and see what you're dealing with. Then limit your iterations to, say, 20 or so, to see where `term` first fails to have the value you expect.)*

Comment: Note that this is the Taylor expansion of function sin(x) ***at x=0***. So you'd better not use that as an approximation for large x. But good news: sin is a periodic function. Just remove or add 2pi from x until x is in range (-pi, +pi] and the results will already be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

The bug is in integer overflow of `fact`. There should be a check that integer overflow hasn't happened.

```
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main(){
    double x;
    double sinx;
    int n=1;
    int sign=-1;
    std::cin>>x;
    sinx=0;
    bool overflow = false;

    for(;;) {
        int64_t fact=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=2*n+1;i++){
            old_fact = fact;
            fact = fact * i;
            // check for overflow
            if (fact / i != old_fact) {
               overflow = true;
               break;
            }
        }
        if (overflow)
           break;


        double term=std::pow(x,2*n+1)/fact;
        if(term==0){
            break;
        }
        std::cout<<"n=" << n << ", fact = " << fact << ", term: " << term <<"\n";
        sinx += term * sign;
        sign *= -1;
        n++;
        std::cout<<"sinx=" << sinx<<"\n\n";
    }
    std::cout<<sinx;
}
```

godblot link: https://godbolt.org/z/zP8sT6ovq

### Old answer:

The problem is with checking if a [floating point number is exactly equal to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19837576/811335).

```cpp
        if(term==0){
```

This may not ever evaluate to true. It may keep oscillating around a value close to zero. What you could do is to compare if `term` is arbitrarily close to zero. You can hard code a value like 0.000001 (which I recommend for a class project) or you can use [epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) if you want to get more technical.

So the code will be like:

```cpp
if (std::abs(term) < 0.000001) {
  break;
```

Comment: If you have a loop that is always making the number smaller (each iteration always multiplies by something < 1.0), it will eventually underflow to 0.0, so this is one (rare) case where an `==` test with floating point values makes sense.

Comment: true. i just verified it. the problem is with integer overflow. edited the answer.

Comment: I've come up with another solution in the meantime, following the answer above and this is how I implemented the answer. Have I done it right? 
https://pastebin.com/u3BhrUb0

Answer (score 3):

Your basic problem is using an `int` to calculate fact (factorial), which will overflow pretty quickly, leading to undefined behavior.

Change that to `double` and things should work, as `double` has much larger range (won't overflow so soon), and even when it does, the overflow is well-defined, giving ∞

---

You can make it much more efficient by not recomputing *n!* and *x<sup>n</sup>* from scratch each iteration of the loop -- just multiply the term by `x*x` and divide it by `(2*n)*(2*n+1.0)`

Another problem you may see is loss of precision when *x* is large.  This is a general problem with using series expansions like this -- for a periodic function like *sin* for real use, you generally want to do range reduction first.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments about your code:

- I ***very strongly*** recommend you put all the `sin` calculations in a function called `sin`, and leave only the input and output logic in the `main` function.
- The formula you have been given is the Taylor expansion of sin(x) at x = 0. It gives a good approximation of sin(x) when x is close to 0, but quickly becomes completely wrong when x is large. In fact I recommend to only use it for x in range [-pi/3, +pi/3]. Fortunately, sinus is periodic, so you can remove `2 pi` from x until x is in range [-pi, +pi]; and then you can use the trigonometric formula `sin(x) = 2 * sin(x/2) * cos(x/2)` and `cos(x) = cos(x/2) * cos(x/2) - sin(x/2) * sin(x/2)` to divide `x` by 2 before computing its sine.
- The text you have been given says *"The algorithm should run until one of the factors reaches 0 value."* This sentence is meaningless. The factors converge towards 0, which means they become closer and closer to 0, but they never reach 0. Fortunately, the Taylor expansion is good enough if you have taken care to reduce x to range [-pi/4, +pi/4]: the error will be below 0.00001 even for small values of n.
- Since `x^(2n + 3) == x^(2n+1) * x^2` and `fact(2n + 3) == fact(2n + 1) * (2n + 2) * (2n + 3)`, you don't need to recompute the powers of x and the factorials from scratch at every iteration.
- If you can use a proper `for`-loop with an explicit counter, upper-bound, and increment, then use it! It makes the code a lot easier to read and debug than using `for(;;)` and then breaking the loop unannounced with `break`.
- Since we want to reduce x to range [-pi/4, +pi/4] and then use the Taylor expansion only in that range, I recommend putting the range reduction logic in one function, and the Taylor expansion logic in another function.

With all this in mind:

```cpp
#include <stdio>

double mysin(double x)
{
    double twopi = 6.283185307179586;
    double    pi = 3.141592653589793;
    while (x > pi)
    {
        x -= twopi;
    }
    while (x < -pi)
    {
        x += twopi;
    }
    double sinx4 = mysin_taylor(x / 4);
    double cosx4 = mycos_taylor(x / 4);
    return (4 * sinx4 * cosx4 * (cosx4 * cosx4 - sinx4 * sinx4));
}

/* Only use mysin_taylor(x) for -pi/3 < x < pi/3 */
double mysin_taylor(double x)
{
    unsigned int n = 11;
    double x2 = x * x;
    double xk = x;
    double ck = 1.0;
    double sinx = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int k = 1; k <= n; k += 2)
    {
        sinx += ck * xk;
        xk *= x2;
        ck *= (-1) / ((k+1)*(k+2));
    }
    return (sinx);

/* Only use mycos_taylor(x) for -pi/3 < x < pi/3 */
double mycos_taylor(double x)
{
    unsigned int n = 10;
    double x2 = x * x;
    double xk = 1.0;
    double ck = 1.0;
    double cosx = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k <= n; k += 2)
    {
        cosx += ck * xk;
        xk *= x2;
        ck *= (-1) / ((k+1)*(k+2));
    }
    return (cosx);

int main(){
    double x;
    double sinx;
    std::cin >> x;
    sinx = mysin(x);
    std::cout << sinx;
}
```